# what is the difference between get_header_image() and header_image() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-headers, theme-development

in the process of self learning from the official wordpress theme developement handbook
this [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/) shows how to create headers and two different functions were used:

- [get_header_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header_image/)
- [header_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/header_image/)

both return a string, which is the image URL.
is this just another confusing redundency ? or is there an actual difference between the two.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? It's clearly explained there what these two functions do.

Comment: I don't think my comment was non-constructive: I basically asked you to review the documentation as it does clearly state that one function _echoes_ ("Displays...") an image URL while the other returns it. You likely skimmed through the pages without really paying attention to what the documentation said, and now you get mad because someone pointed that out?

Comment: @Amine "both return a string" - no, only [`get_header_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header_image/#return) has a *return* value. And developer.wordpress.org/reference is a *code reference* website, so do take time to review the source code (like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header_image/#source) or [here on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L1172)) when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

### Semantic

#### dis·play

Make a prominent exhibition of (something) in a place where it can be easily seen.

> the palace used to display a series of Flemish tapestries.

#### re·trieve

get or bring (something) back; regain possession of.

> I was sent to retrieve the balls from his garden

---

### How

While `header_image()` will echo out the header image URL, `get_header_image()` will not.

```
<?php

header_image();

get_header_image();
```

`header_image()` is a wrapper for `get_header_image()`. Mainly used on the front-end, the role is to escape and echo out get_header_image().

```
<?php

/**
 * Displays header image URL.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/header_image/
 */
function header_image() {
    $image = get_header_image();
 
    if ( $image ) {
        echo esc_url( $image );
    }
}
```

A practical use case of `get_header_image()` would be inside a function.

WordPress use that `get_ ...` distinction for most of it's default functions, eg:

- `get_the_title()` and `the_title()`.
- `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and `the_post_thumbnail()`.
- `get_the_content()` and `the_content()`.
  ... etc.

Comment: Upvoted your answer since you were kind enough to invest time on this.

Comment: @Amine Keep in mind that the CODEX is a community based project. User a free to submit edits to make it better. Don't hesitate to do so!

Comment: as a personal opinion: these get_* functions are unnecessary superfluous way to echo something and confusing. Using the native php echo is shorter !!!

Comment: @amarinediary thank you again, am actually investigating how to (the process is complicated with slack channels etc) Because i found a code error in one page (not a languistic confusion)

Comment: You can do so via the GitHub Wordpress profile page, under repo. If my answer was helpful don't forget to accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Someone posted it then deleted it quickly, but just for the sake of benefiting everyone who is looking for an answer:
`header_image()` will echo the URL without the need of using the php `echo`. While `get_header_image()` will also return the image URL but it **doesn't** echo it. You **have** to use the php **echo** for it.
NB: this isn't mentioned in the official documentation, unless am blind I challenge anyone to show me where it says **echo** in the official page, or where this distinction is explained.

Comment: Since you asked, here: https://i.postimg.cc/2SQKyKJT/Screenshot-2021-05-05-090032.png

Comment: It is. I'm guessing English isn't your native language tho. One states `Retrieves header image for custom header` the other one `Displays header image URL`. The nuance is in Display and Retrieve.

Comment: @cabrerahector this is the core code for the function, again: it's not explained in the documentation. I will not go read the entire core code trying to understand it ! The documentation exists for a reason. Can you upload another image ? Where it says echo in the documentation. Cheers